# What built in function can I use to get the last 3 elements in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

**I wanted to get the last 3 items or elements in a list. Also making sure that my code works no matter how many items are in the list.**

```
sports_goods=["bat","ball","base_ball","hockey","basket_ball"]
```

I have tried to use Splice(:-1) and also sports_goods[-1]
but, couldn't get it working.

```
sports_goods=[bat,ball,base_ball,hockey,basket_ball]
```

**My code is**

```
sports_goods.splice(-3:-1) 
And 
sports_goods[-1]
```

**Expected result:**

```
The last 3 elements which are base_ball, hockey and basket_ball.
```

**Actual results:**

```
Shows error...Name error to be specific.
```

Comment: Name error? I would expect `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splice'`.

Comment: NameError would come when creating the list because he didnt quote his strings. he has since edited the post to quote the strings. but before the edit they were raw words not quoted as strings. So the error that would have come would be `NameError: name 'bat' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

you should at least post valid python code. your list isnt valid since your words are not wrapped in quotes to make them strings. However if you have a list you can just select elements from the third last index to the end like so

```
sports_goods=['bat', 'ball', 'base_ball', 'hockey', 'basket_ball']
print('the last 3 elements are: ', ", ".join(sports_goods[-3:]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
the last 3 elements are:  base_ball, hockey, basket_ball
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just edited my post. Thanks for your answer :)